# Currying using python with-statement?

Tags: python, currying, with-statement

I am not sure if this is 'good python practice', but would it be possible to, say, define a custom File-object that could do something like:

```
myfile = myopen('myfile.txt')
with myfile:
    write('Hello World!') #notice we don't put "myfile.write(..)" here!
```

i.e the File-context creates a *function* "write()" so that we don't have to type myfile.write(..) etc. It saves typing and makes the purpose clearer in some cases. For instance:

```
myboard = ChessBoard()
with ChessBoard():
    make_move("e4")
    make_move("e5")
    give_up()
```

as opposed to

```
myboard = ChessBoard()
with ChessBoard():
    make_move("e4",board=myboard)
    make_move("e5",board=myboard)
    give_up(board=myboard)
```

The question is: should I do this? and HOW can I do it? I am guessing I would have to modify the globals()-dict somehow, but that seems like a bad idea..

EDIT: Ok thanks! I got multiple good answers advising me not to do this. So I won't do it :o)

Comment: "should I do this?" - no. "how can I do it?" - no way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not what context managers are for and, as has been remarked, I beats the "explicit is better than implicit" principle. The only way to make it work would have to work around Python's compositional semantics, which are one of its strong points. What you can do to save typing, if there's only a single method to be called multiple times, is:

```
move = ChessBoard().make_move
move("e4")
move("e5")
```

Or with multiple such methods:

```
board = ChessBoard()
move = board.make_move
give_up = board.give_up
# call methods
```

(In FP terms, this is actually partial application, not currying.)

Answer (score 1):

You'd think you'd need to modify `globals()`. But if you defined the context manager in a different module from the one you're using it in, you'd be using the globals of the module where it was defined. Not the module where it was being used. So you'd need to define the methods in the `__builtin__` namespace (where the built-in functions are). This can certainly be done, but it strikes me as an even worse idea, *especially* if you're wanting to use it with arbitrary objects. *Maybe* if you mangled the name in some way (e.g., adding a leading underscore). But even then, what if you nested the `with` statements?

You're looking for Python's `with` statement to be like Pascal's or Visual Basic's, and it's just not the same thing at all. That said, a Python equivalent to the Pascal/VB `with` statement would be a lovely thing to have; it just couldn't be called `with`.

Answer (score 1):

First off, this is not a good idea *at all*. Explicit is better than implicit -- by explicitly mentioning the board, the reader (which may be you in a few weeks!) can instantly tell which board is being operated on. Also, there is no need. You can have more convenient syntax in other ways: For example, make the functions methods of the individual objects. And drop the pointless context manager (what's it supposed to do? You already create an object beforehand!).

To do this, you'd need global state, but not `globals` specifically. Say, a global (module-level to be exact) stack of objects, the context manager pushes and pops the object, and the individual functions look at the top of that stack. It actually wouldn't be too hard to implement if you know your stuff, but as I said before, there is no reason to.

Answer (score 0):

One (at least half-crazy) way of doing that would be something like:

```
@contextmanager
def export(obj, *atts):
    yield [getattr(obj, a) for a in atts]
```

and then:

```
class X:
   def foo...
   def bar...

with export(some_x, 'foo', 'bar') as (foo, bar):
      foo() <-- some_x.foo
      bar() <-- some_x.bar
```

Of course, like any other similar solution this makes zero sense in real life.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, this is probably a very bad idea, but I do see some limited cases (perhaps as a make-shift DSL) where it might be workable.

```
class ChessBoard(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
    def __enter__(self):
        self.handle = open(self.filename, 'w')
        globals()['move'] = self.move
        globals()['give_up'] = self.give_up
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.handle.close()
    def move(self, move):
        self.handle.write(move + '\n')
    def give_up(self):
        self.handle.write('resign' + '\n')

with ChessBoard('chess.txt'):
    move('e4')
    move('e5')
    give_up()
```

Comment: The implementation is awful, because it breaks nesting of context managers (and needlessly mucks with `globals` -- what's wrong with `global`?).

Comment: @delnan It's awful for many more reasons than that. I'd hoped my introductory disclaimer would indicate that the use case for this is extremely narrow, though I do see it as potentially useful for a single-module, single-purpose application, or perhaps as generated code.

Comment: I meant awful under the assumption that we want to do this. Of course, it's probably a bad idea to do it in the first place, but if we're doing it, we can and should do it better than in the way you propose. See my answer for a quick sketch of how it can be done better.

Comment: @delnan I disagreed with the rationale and method described in your answer. If you don't like this example, I invite you to use the power of your downvote.

Comment: I'd be more interested to hear *why* you disagree with the implementation I suggest. Because it requires the functions to be aware of the global state?